# Unable to access cookie in HttpRequest

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm trying to do a “get” of a page, and pass in a list of ids that is stored in my cookie. My assumption was that it would be possible to get the cookie with the list from my request. However, I don’t get the cookie on the server side as I would expect. I only get a “user” cookie, but that doesn’t contain my info.

I want to try to avoid actually passing these values in the URL as I'm trying to keep as clean and nice URL's as possible. However, if it isn't possible in any other way, then I can still do it.

Adding the cookie:

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());
    var expires = 30 * 1000 * 60;

    var c_name = name; 
    var exdate = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + value + ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString();
}
```

Getting the new page in jQuery:

```
document.location.href = href;
```

In my Action Method:

```
if (Request.Cookies != null)
{
    var myCookie = Request.Cookies[cookieName];
}
//myCookie is always null
```

Shouldn't a cookie I add, still be accessible in the Request?

Edit:

When I've now used FireBug and FireCookie, I can see that the cookie is not passed with the request. So the question is if I do something wrong when adding the cookie?

Comment: Did you make sure the cookie is in an accessible domain before sending to the server? You can use a tool like Firecookie to get this information.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683/

Comment: I am not sure about ASP.NET part, but to get the browser to send the cookie along the request, its domain **and** path should match the request URI. Concentrate you on that part first.

Comment: Setting cookies is an annoyance in javascript. Since you're using jQuery, I'd recommend the cookie plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie.

Comment: The cookie is accessible. I've used FireCookie, and I can see my cookie and all the content that I would expect in it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I couldn't access the cookie was because of the cookie path. When I was looking thru FireCookie, the path was the only thing not matching with the cookie that was accessible in the request.

The one that was accessible was looking like this:

```
Path: "/"
```

and the one that I wanted to access, but was unable to, was looking like this:

```
Path: "/{projectName}/{controller}/{action}"
```

So when I'm now saving my cookie, I changed it from being this:

```
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + value + ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString();
```

To be this instead:

```
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + value + ";Path=/;expires=" + exdate.toGMTString();
```

And it all works out fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. what about creating the cookie in the server side by calling a handler?

```
// on CookieHandler.ashx
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Your Data");
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

and in your javascript method you can invoke your cookie handler by using XmlHttpRequest object or JSON call.

```
         function setCookie(name, value){
         var cookieQuery= 'AppCode/cookieHandler.ashx?name='+name+'&value='+value;
             var xmlhttp;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
             else
             if (window.ActiveXObject) {
             // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             else {
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
             }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                   // Do Something
                   //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
             }

             xmlhttp.open("GET", cookieQuery, true);
             xmlhttp.send(null); // Sends the request to the server.

          }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wouldn't the same data be available to him in the Controller as would be available in the .ashx file?